# Alternative to \includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using Ti*k*Z to include an image in a header and have found that if an image rolls onto the next page then Ti*k*Z includes it in place of the header on the next page (basically, Ti*k*Z appears to just grab the wrong image). Are there alternatives to `\includegraphics` that I could use in hopes that I don't can hack my way around this?

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\HeadAndFoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% logo
\node[anchor=north west, xshift=250, yshift=-20] (logo) at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=100pt]{figA}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\HeadAndFoot}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}


\end{document}
```

figA.png is 401x146 pixels
figB.png is 630x128 pixels

When I do this I get a title page with no logo (expected), a second page with "figB" in the logo splot (surprise) and a third page with "figA" in the logo spot.

Comment: Can you make a small compilable example that illustrates your problem? Perhaps it is easier to solve the underlying problem instead of looking for an alternative to `\includegraphic`.

Comment: Welcome! `I'm using tikz to include an image in a header ...` This sounds like a mistake. (Though it is hard to tell without an example.) You might use Ti*k*Z in a header, but it sounds as if you might be using it to create the header.

Comment: Actually, \includegraphics is from the graphicx package and can be used independently of TikZ.

Comment: I suspect your header is using the image in some sort of a savebox, and your code is overwriting the contents of the box. Perhaps just post the code that does the header if you can't make a small example that shows the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `tikz`, then you also have the `pgf` basic layer commands, so instead of using `\includegraphics` you can declare an image with `\pgfdeclareimage` and later use it with `\pgfuseimage`. (This actually makes more sense here given that you're repeatedly using the same image with the same scaling applied.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=100pt]{A}{figA}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\textwidth]{B}{figB}

\newcommand\HeadAndFoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% logo
\node[anchor=north west, xshift=250, yshift=-20] (logo) at (current page.north west) 
{\pgfuseimage{A}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\HeadAndFoot}

\begin{document}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\pgfuseimage{B}

\end{document}
```

This uses the `figA` image at the top of the second and third pages.

As for what's causing the problem, at first I thought it might have been an interaction with the `remember picture` option, but the issue can be reproduced without it:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newcommand\HeadAndFoot{\includegraphics[width=100pt]{figA}}


\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\HeadAndFoot}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\end{document}
```

So I'm guessing it's something to do with the shipout stuff. Are you using the image as a watermark or a header? If it's a header, perhaps it would be simpler to incorporate it into the page style.

Comment: When you wrote, "perhaps it would be simpler to incorporate it into the page style." I could not find an example of that. I was looking [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121393/tikz-header-and-footer-across-top-and-bottom-of-bulletin-newsletter-page?noredirect=1&lq=1) where the answer suggested this method. I also wonder if there is an advantage to that.

Comment: I should mention that all of my distances are from a graphic designer and measured relative to the page's "north west". So, I'm not hoping for help form LaTeX in laying out the header and footer.

Comment: @pdb Depends on your document, but have you considered [flowfram](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram)? See, for example, the `sample-brochure` file in http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/samples. There's also a [GUI to help with the layout](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/).