# tikz header mixing up figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using Ti*k*Z to include an image in a header and have found that if an image rolls onto the next page then Ti*k*Z includes it in place of the header on the next page (basically, Ti*k*Z appears to just grab the wrong image). Are there alternatives to `\includegraphics` that I could use in hopes that I don't can hack my way around this?

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\HeadAndFoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% logo
\node[anchor=north west, xshift=250, yshift=-20] (logo) at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=100pt]{figA}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\HeadAndFoot}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}


\end{document}
```

figA.png is 401x146 pixels
figB.png is 630x128 pixels

When I do this I get a title page with no logo (expected), a second page with "figB" in the logo splot (surprise) and a third page with "figA" in the logo spot.

NOTE: I asked this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329999/alternative-to-includegraphics) before but cannot access the login to edit it with a MWE (I thought I was logged in, first post on this part of SE). An edit to add a MWE was rejected. A MWE would also not be an "answer" I don't know how to proceed but to repost with an account I have access to.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Looks like it will take a bit because the automated system would only let me remove the one i can log into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear why you aren't just using the standard latex header mechanism nor quite where tikz is getting confused, but saving the image in a box seems to get things back on track

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newbox\mybox
\sbox\mybox{\includegraphics[width=100pt]{figA}}
\newcommand\HeadAndFoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% logo
\node[anchor=north west, xshift=250, yshift=-20] (logo) at (current page.north west) {\usebox{\mybox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\HeadAndFoot}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figB}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tested with `eso-pic` without `TikZ` (`\AddToShipoutPicture{\put(0,0){\parbox[b][100pt]{100pt}{ \vfill\centering\includegraphics[width=100pt]{figA}\vfill}}}`) and the result also shows `figA` instead of `figB`. Is it the same problem?

Comment: @Ignasi no idea:-) but why not just put the figure in a heading, you are using `\pagestyle{empty}` so disabling all latex's standard heading code,

Comment: This is a minimal working example. There is a lot of other TikZ in the non-minimal case I'm using. I also wanted to be able to place the logo in an exact spot. I didn't see how to do that with a standard header.

Comment: To more fully answer why I'm using TikZ, I'm doing something similar to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121393/tikz-header-and-footer-across-top-and-bottom-of-bulletin-newsletter-page) but with an image in there too.

Comment: @pdb I can see why use tikz to draw the fancy border and text but I'd just add that tikz as the content of a standard header rather then using some overlay code to add it to a page without head or foot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I would be happy to do it that way but didn't see how. Is there a benefit to doing it that way?