# Draw rectangle on bottom of page with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle and position it on the bottom of the page. So as I am pretty new to tikz, I am not quite sure how to it. Lets say I want it to look like this hard coded triangle:

```
\tikz \fill[blue] (3,3) -- (18, 3) -- (19,4) -- cycle;
```

Now, I found information that I need to use nodes to get coordinates relative to the page. SO I have to define nodes, and store the coordinates, right?

```
\node (A) at (current page.south west) {};
\node (B) at (current page.south east) {};
\coordinate (cA) at (A) ;
\coordinate (cB) at (B);
```

So know my problem is, that I don't know how to specify the third coordinates, as they are not relative to the page. What I want for example is, that the triangle has a "height" of given length (lets say 2 cm...)

```
\draw[line width=1mm] (cA) -- (cB) -- (??) -- cycle;
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please complete your snippets to something we can compile? Can you explain what the role of this figure is? Is it content you want to put in a `figure`, say? Is it a footer? is it something that should be background, behind the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key insight you are missing is that to specify relative coordinates you can use `++`. For example, from `(current page.south east)` if you want to draw a line 2 cm up from this point, simply write `(current page.south east)--++(0,2cm)`. This means, move 2cm in the `y` direction from the previous coordinate, with no change in the `x` direction.

To get back across the page to coordinate 2cm above `(current page.south west)` I've used the `-|` command, which tells Ti*k*Z to find the right angle intersection point between the two coordinates. Note there is an opposite version of this called `|-` which would in this case return the coordinate `(current page.south east)`.

So all in all, the path you want for this rectangle is `(current page.south west) -- (current page.south east) --++(0,2cm) -| (current page.south west) -- cycle`.
So in one exercise you've now learnt two really useful drawing commands in Ti*k*Z. There are of course a number of other ways to do it, one of which is using `rectangle` as shown in John Kormylo's answer.

Additionally, If you want this 'footer' to appear on every page, then you can use something like this.

I've put the Ti*k*Z code in a command I've named `\Footer` and then used the package `atbegshi` as described in [TikZ header and footer across top and bottom of bulletin/newsletter page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121393/tikz-header-and-footer-across-top-and-bottom-of-bulletin-newsletter-page/).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newcommand\Footer{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill [remember picture,overlay,blue] (current page.south west) -- (current page.south east) --++(0,2cm) -| (current page.south west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\Footer}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\Footer}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understood now the relative to coordinate information. I also like your suggestion if I want to put it on every page. But another question here - Is it also possible to do it by using tikz and the background setups??

Comment: I haven't got an answer for that. But by all means go ahead and write a new question on the site.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to run it twice.  Note: tikzpagenodes will give you access to the location of the header, footer, text and marginpar areas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[blue] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,2cm);
\end{document}
```