# tikz: draw line with offset relative to page top/bottom

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a horizontal line using tikz relative to the page top/bottom.
Something similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443746/223046), but using a line (simple `\draw`). What I have so far:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw[thin, gray, anchor=south] (-11,-20.4) -- (11,-20.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My goal is to get rid of the absolute coordinates and replace them with i.e. `current page.north` and an offset of e.g. `2cm`, but I wasn't able to figure it out yet.
Any hints or tricks are greatly appreciated, thx!

**EDIT:** (figured it out thx to the input below)

```tex
\newcommand\mOffset{2.8} % margin offset of vertical bar from top/bottom [cm]
% top bar
\draw[thin, gray] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\mOffset)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\mOffset)$);
% bottom bar
\draw[thin, gray] ($(current page.south west)+(0,\mOffset)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+(0,\mOffset)$);
```

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credits to Milo, since you only have to adapt the code you linked your question to. Then with use of the `calc` Ti*k*Z library, you can adjust the gap you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\diagline{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
% from one corner to the other
%\draw [remember picture,overlay,blue] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east); 

%With a gap of 1%
\draw [remember picture,overlay,blue] ($(current page.south west)!0.05!(current page.north east)$) -- ($(current page.south west)!0.95!(current page.north east)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\diagline}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\diagline}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

Without gap:

[image: from corner to corner]

With 1 % gap:

[image: with some blank]

Comment: Thx for the pointer...figured it out thanks to your input!